# Event delegation with input oninput event

Tags: javascript, input, event-delegation

Is it somehow possible to set up `oninput` event delegation to change the text of the `changeText` div?

```
<div id="manyInputs">
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="changeText">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="changeText">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="changeText">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla JS solution that would work is to bind the "change" event to your "manyInputs" div and grab the target element from the event handler and look for it's next sibling. If you don't know the structure of your code then you could also add an data-id to the input then use that id to find your text div to add the value to.

HTML

```
<div id="manyInputs">
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="changeText"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="changeText" ></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
        <span class="changeText"></span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('manyInputs');
inputs.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var value = e.target.value;
    e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = value;
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s7wtevbu/

JS Fiddle with data-id solution: https://jsfiddle.net/kas1h6xe/

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is by using jquery's `.keyup()` function. Which allows you to bind an event handler to the "keyup" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element..

Html:

```
<div id="manyInputs">
  <div>
    <input id="input1" type="text" data-div-id="divForInput1">
    <div id="divForInput1" class="changeText"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="input2" type="text" data-div-id="divForInput2">
    <div id="divForInput2" class="changeText"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="input3" type="text" data-div-id="divForInput3">
    <div id="divForInput3" class="changeText"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
       $('#' + $(this).attr('data-div-id')).text($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

You can try this example I made in jsfiddle (Make sure you hit the "Run" button at the top):

https://jsfiddle.net/gLxxj21h/1/

Comment: This way I need to set up many event handlers, but is it somehow possible to use only 1 event handler for many inputs? And if possible in vanilla JS

Comment: A couple things then. 1.) You would need to add some kind of identifier to the div you want to write to. 2.) You need to bind to either a class or the css selector 'input[type=text]' for the keyup. This way it gets bound to all the inputs. See this jsfiddle as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/gLxxj21h/

Comment: I don't recommend doing this in plain vanilla js